# List comparison failing in python3 and here is the sample code

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, comparison

Here is what I have:

```
ListA = ['000C297D-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705872', '000C297D-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705685']
ListB = ['000C297D-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705685','000C297D-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705872', few more such entries]
```

The goal is to check the matching elements. However, I had no luck result for matching comparison even when I used the below techniques:

1. Assign ListA, ListB as a setA and setB respectively and then perform intersection operation it does not find any match.
2. == operator by iterating through the list also did not generate a match.
3. "IN" operator too does not indicate a match.

interestingly, when the union operation is performed on the Set for this, it repeats the entries.

Any pointers on this

Code:

```
for key, value in networkGroup.items():
    print (key,value)
    setA = set(value['ReferenceId'])
    print (setA)
    for k, v in IDIPMap.items():
        print (k,v)
        if (set(k).intersection(setA)):
            print ("Match")
```

Output:

```
Group-Test {'Group Type': 'NetworkObject', 'Id': '000c297d-3667-0ed3-0000-133143995685', 'Name': 'Group-Test', 'ReferenceId': ['000C297D-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705872', '000C297D-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705685'], 'Type': 'NetworkObject'}

{'000C297D-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705685', '000C297D-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705872'}

000c297d-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705872 ['10.106.38.222']
000c297d-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705685 ['10.106.38.221']
```

ideally, the comparison of variable k should match with setA

New Modified code:

```
for key,value in networkGroup.items():
    #print (value['ReferenceId'])
    setA = set()
    setA = set(value['ReferenceId'])
    print (setA)
    for k, v in networkID.items():
        print (v['Id'])
        if (v['Id'] in setA):
            print ("Match")
        if (v['Id'] in value['ReferenceId']):
            print ("Match")
```

Output:

{'000C297D-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705685', '000C297D-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705872'}
000c297d-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705872
000c297d-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705685

Just does not seem to like either of the comparisons. I guess I might be doing a blunder here.

Comment: "Assign ListA, ListB as a setA and setB respectively and then perform intersection operation it does not find any match.": if that doesn't work, it means that there are no common elements. Find why/test with simpler data

Comment: Here is a snapshot of the list and there are common elements present which is why it is weird to see why its not working:

ListA = ['000C297D-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705872', '000C297D-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705685']
ListB = ['000c297d-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705872', '000c297d-3667-0ed3-0000-038654705685']

Created identical lists using the same contents too. 

With simpler data set it works well, the data set for which it works is str, alphanumeric and even IP address.

Comment: post your set intersection code (or better a [mcve]), it is probably wrong

Comment: This is snapshot of the relevant section:
 setA = set (value)
 setB = set (value1)
 if (setA.intersection(setB)):
  print ("Success", setA.intersection(setB))

Comment: problem is `set(k).intersection(setA)` should be `set(v).intersection(setA)`, k is the key  it cannot be your list

Comment: Modified the code, but still the same problem, adding the new code and output in the main question

Answer (score 0):

Seems the answer was in the details.
The UUID were case sensitive and hence the problem, solved it using the upper and lower function.

Answer (score 0):

The set.intersect treats uppercase/lowercase as different things.

You can use:

```
setA={s.lower() for s in setA}
setB={s.lower() for s in setB}
```

Before the intersection to solve the problem.